# Using Android Studio with minimum disk space

Tags: android, android-studio

I have limited disk space and want to start developing android, but it seems that android studio eats a lot of memory! some says it took more than 20 GB.

So the question is: what are the minimum necessary components (android platforms, emulator, ...) to start and how can we use android studio with the most possible minimality?

Also, how does adding each of these components (that are respectively unnecessary) affects the used space?

Comment: Androidstudio will not eat so many memory

Comment: You should probably change the phrase to eats a lot of disk space (or storage). Memory usually refers to RAM.

Comment: mine takes 783M of disk space

Comment: 2G RAM for AS, 1G RAM for Gradle; ~8G HDD for SDK (incl. NDK), 700M HDD for AS, ~2GB HDD for AS config and caches, ~500M HDD for one project + whatever emulators take

Comment: friend tommy C., Thanks for your note, you are right.

Comment: But by the way, it also consumes RAM memory, but this is not the question ;)

Comment: My friend Eugen Pechanec, according to you it takes more than 10.5GB without the emulator. Thank you.

Comment: @A.Harkous - Did any of the answers help you? If so, consider voting them up and accepting an answer. Doing so will increase your reputation and encourage others to answer your future questions. Welcome to the community. Keep posting thoughtful questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2G RAM for AS, 1G RAM for Gradle,

~8G HDD for SDK (incl. NDK),

700M HDD for AS,

~2GB HDD for AS config and caches,

~500M HDD for one project + whatever emulators take

As Eugen Pechanec said as a comment.
I think this is the maximum.

Comment: in my PC, AS folder is about 1.6 GB, and there is "jre" folder inside it which contains another "jre" folder that contains again another "jre" folder which contains repetitive files :))

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Note the link for updated requirements. Those listed here are minimal recommendations by Google. More RAM and Disk space have always been better in my experience.

*Requirements as of Nov, 2015*

Just check out the Android Studio [system requirements](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements). You will probably need 4GB RAM and 2GB of disk space to run the Android Studio platform minimally (this is Google's official development platform for Android devices). You can start by downloading the IDE at the [developer website](https://developer.android.com/develop/index.html) and also pickup some [samples](https://developer.android.com/samples/index.html). So the samples will also take up disk space. Depending on how many versions of Android you intend to support you could be using a lot of disk space for the SDKs and emulators, so you should consider carefully which [versions](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) make sense to support.

[image: android-device-coverage]

You might also want to take a spin through the default [training site](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html).

Comment: just 0.3% using Marshmallow? God, i love having a Nexus phone ;-)

Comment: In the System Requirements page, they mentioned disk space consumed by the program itself, but as you know AS does not work alone. for example it needs the SDK...that's an additional 700MB, it needs one platform minimum and a standalone emulator... all these consumes there own. That's why I'am asking. I want to have an answer from someone who really tried it. but anyway, thanks for you, I didn`t notice that on android developers site before, it really helped.

Comment: I would say that there's nobody in the world who can use AS with 2GB of storage!

Comment: @Ehsan - thanks, fixed a poor word choice here to highlight that this is Googles' stated minimum. Couldn't agree more that reality is very different.

Answer (score 0):

Hello friend its true that android studio take lots of space while running, and emulator takes lots of memory so better way to run the program is on Android device, Go to the settings --> Developer options --> USB debugging (ON) if your phone didn't show developer options then Go to --> About device --> and click 7 to 8 times on Build number, it enable your Developer option

Comment: Thanks my friend for your suggestion, I am planning to do this for debugging, but in both methods you better have a good IDE, but considering that the choice of ECLIPSE is weak in my situation, I want to know details about AS.

Answer (score 0):

Install just one android version, then you should be fine...

If you have a native android device, you don't need an emulator you can use the android device to debug. You can debug over USB or WLAN.
Or you could use android x86 on an other machine(Virtual Machine).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a i5 and at least 4gigs of Ram, you should be really fine.
In case of disk space, it depends, I use only the newer SDKs and it takes only about 700mb disk space. 
If you really need all SDK versions, sure it will be more, but I do not think you will need 20 GB even if you add some more versions.

Comment: I have android SDK already, and it takes exactly as you said, but I wanted to know exactly how much does Android Studio adds practically. Thank you.